# Adding side by side vertical slider inside fullPage.js section

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

Would anyone have an idea on how to create [this kind of effect](http://codepen.io/virmasalo/pen/aZojNv) for transitions between fullPage.js section-elements.

```
<div id="fullpage"> 
 <div class="section"></div>
 <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

I've been trying many many different variations, but can't figure out anything that works well.

In words; Transition from section to another shoud have a visual effect that seems like two vertical sliders rolling against each other.

Thanks!

Comment: Easy. Just duplicate your sections ? :D

Comment: @Alvaro Sorry, I had a typo on the code and it was not what I meant. Could you check it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen my other library [multiScroll.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/multiScroll/) ?

It does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I had missed that one.